# quicksort in python always return a unsorted array

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

i defined a quicksort in python.It printed a sorted list, but the return list is unsorted.
[1, 5, 7, 8] #this is result of print(array) in quicksort
[7, 5, 8, 1] #this is result of testing
it's so weired

```
def quickSort(array):
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array

    p = 0  #pivot
    pointer = p + 1
    left = []
    pivot = []
    right = []
    pivot.append(array[p])
    
    #devide array into 3 arrays
    while pointer < len(array):
        if array[pointer] < array[p]:
            left.append(array[pointer])
        elif array[pointer] > array[p]:
            right.append(array[pointer])
        else:
            pivot.append(array[pointer])
            #pointer moves towards right
        pointer += 1
    
    print(left)
    print(pivot)
    print(right)
    array = quickSort(left) + pivot + quickSort(right)
    print(array)
    #concatenation of the 3 arrays
    return (array)
    
array = [7,5,8,1] 
quickSort(array)
print(array)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the event that you pass arguments like whole numbers, strings or tuples to a function, the passing is like call-by-value because you can not change the value of the immutable objects being passed to the function.

Example:-

```
string = "Yash"
def test(string):
    string = "Yash Mehta"
    print("Inside Function:", string)

test(string)  #Yash Mehta
print("Outside Function:", string) #Yash
```

you can store the answer by making another variable which store list..

```
def quickSort(array):
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array
    p = 0  #pivot
    pointer = p + 1
    left = []
    pivot = []
    right = []
    pivot.append(array[p])
    
    #dvide array into 3 arrays
    while pointer < len(array):
        if array[pointer] < array[p]:
            left.append(array[pointer])
        elif array[pointer] > array[p]:
            right.append(array[pointer])
        else:
            pivot.append(array[pointer])
            #pointer moves towards right
        pointer += 1
    
    print(left)
    print(pivot)
    print(right)
    array = quickSort(left) + pivot + quickSort(right)
    print(array)
    #concatenation of the 3 arrays
    return array
    
array = [7,5,8,1] 
sorted_array=quickSort(array)
print(sorted_array)
```

Output:

```
[5, 1]
[7]
[8]
[1]
[5]
[]
[1, 5]
[1, 5, 7, 8]
[1, 5, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing pointer and reference in Java (or C# or C++) language. Your problem is the functional programming paradigm. Python supports 3 paradigms simultaneously. Therefore, when you give an argument to a function, the value of the argument does not normally change.

You need to assign function return to variable to use it.

```
def quickSort(array):
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array

    p = 0  # pivot
    pointer = p + 1
    left = []
    pivot = []
    right = []
    pivot.append(array[p])

    # devide array into 3 arrays
    while pointer < len(array):
        if array[pointer] < array[p]:
            left.append(array[pointer])
        elif array[pointer] > array[p]:
            right.append(array[pointer])
        else:
            pivot.append(array[pointer])
            # pointer moves towards right
        pointer += 1

    print(left)
    print(pivot)
    print(right)
    array = quickSort(left) + pivot + quickSort(right)
    print(array)
    # concatenation of the 3 arrays
    return array


array = [7, 5, 8, 1]
array = quickSort(array)
print(array)
# or
response_array = quickSort(array)
print(response_array)
```

(edit) EXTRA COMMENT ADDED:

if you want to change your argument value without using global variable, let me explain more before revised your code. first you look at below code:

```
def sample():
    x = 0
    print(id(x), x.y_var)
    increment2(x)
    print(id(x), x.y_var)

def increment(x):
    print(id(x), x)
    x = x + 1
    print(id(x), x)

sample()
```

the sample output will be like

```
2421700716816 0
2421700716816 0
2421700716848 1
2421700716816 0
```

as you could realize python created new variable, you need to return it for reach its value, but if you create a class as you will see below:

```
class Y:
    y_var = 0

def sample():
    x = Y()
    print(id(x), x.y_var)
    increment(x)
    print(id(x), x.y_var)

def increment(x:Y):
    print(id(x), x.y_var)
    x.y_var = x.y_var + 1
    print(id(x), x.y_var)

sample()
```

the object created from the Y class id is not changed after calling function, so you can use it without need to return it. Sample output is:

```
1594815643600 0
1594815643600 0
1594815643600 1
1594815643600 1
```

I changed your code as below with using @soudipta-dutta sample code; it is more pythonic:

```
class MyArray:
    my_list = []


def quick_sort(array: MyArray):
    if len(array.my_list) < 2:
        return array.my_list
    else:
        pivot = array.my_list[0]
        left = MyArray()
        left.my_list = [i for i in array.my_list[1:] if i <= pivot]
        right = MyArray()
        right.my_list = [i for i in array.my_list[1:] if i > pivot]
        array.my_list = quick_sort(left) + [pivot] + quick_sort(right)
        return array.my_list
    
    
my_array = MyArray()
my_array.my_list = [7, 5, 8, 1]
quick_sort(my_array)
print(my_array.my_list)
```

output is

```
[1, 5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggest does work! If i want to change the value of argument, normally how could we do?  I also wrote a selectionSort ,but this function can change the value of argument directly.                                                                                                                     ```def selectionSort(array):
   n = len(array)
   for i in range(n - 1):
     min = i
     for j in range(i + 1, n):
        if array[j]< array[min]:
            min = j
     array[i],array[min]=array[min],array[i]```

Comment: because you haven't created a new list. list is an object created from the list class. It's okay since you just change its content instead of creating a new object, just like I did for quick_sort.